# Get sortered result from obtained in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here i want to get result only if both the numbers are present for both `type`. For example in this number `888` is present only for `super` type and `000` is present only for type `box`. I don't want to list only the number that is present for only one `type`. Want to get the numbers if it is present for both the `type`. Here is my code please have a look

```
 $query=$this->db->query("
SELECT T.number
     , W.number
     , max(T.MOST_FREQUENT) max_val
     , W.MOST_FREQUENT
     , W.product_id 
  from 
     ( SELECT product_id
            ,date_status
            ,number
            , bill_details.id as b_id
            , SUM(quantity ) AS MOST_FREQUENT 
         FROM bill_details
        WHERE date_status = 1 
          AND product_id IN(8,7)
        GROUP 
           BY product_id,number
       HAVING SUM(quantity) >= $d_limit_3
        ORDER 
           BY SUM(quantity) DESC 
        LIMIT 500 
     ) T
  JOIN
     ( SELECT product_id
            ,date_status
            ,number
            , bill_details.id as b_id
            , SUM(quantity) AS MOST_FREQUENT 
         FROM bill_details
        WHERE date_status = 1 
          AND product_id IN(8,7)
        GROUP 
           BY product_id
            , number
       HAVING SUM(quantity) >= $d_limit_3
        ORDER 
           BY SUM(quantity) DESC 
        LIMIT 500
     ) W 
    ON T.number = W.number
 group 
    by T.number
     , W.MOST_FREQUENT
     , W.product_id
     , W.number 
 ORDER 
    BY concat(lpad(max(T.MOST_FREQUENT), 100, '0'), T.number)  DESC
     , T.number
     , W.MOST_FREQUENT
     , W.product_id
");
        return $query->result();
```

Here is my output[image]

Comment: A good tip is 'NEVER use SELECT *'

Comment: i had removed that

Comment: I still see it.

Comment: Such a complicated query for such an easy task... not sure if it's a good idea to stress database that much